# #1064 Error SQL - Happens on all my procedures/functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question has been asked a bunch in different forms, but none of the ones I looked at (quite a bit) seemed to help me out in my specific case. I wrote a few functions and procedures and I always get the same error at the same spot. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STUDENTS_BY_STATUS;
CREATE PROCEDURE STUDENTS_BY_STATUS (sts VARCHAR(10))
  BEGIN
  SELECT BannerId, Name FROM STUDENT WHERE Status = sts;
END |
DELIMITER;
```

This happens on all my procedures functions, this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'CREATE PROCEDURE STUDENTS_BY_STATUS (sts VARCHAR(10))
>       BEGIN
>       SELECT BannerId,' at line 2

On my other one its this:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'CREATE FUNCTION GoodGrade(letGrade VARCHAR(2)) RETURNS int
>       BEGIN
>           DECLARE v' at line 2

This happens whether or not I use | or // as the DELIMITER...can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Phpmyadmin, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've changed the delimiter, written a statement and then not delimited it according to your new definition

Change the line

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STUDENTS_BY_STATUS;
```

to

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS STUDENTS_BY_STATUS |
```

### Update

This wasn't obvious from the initial error message, but you have another error when you reset the Delimiter after the procedure definition. You need a space before the ';' on that one.

so change

```
DELIMITER;
```

to

```
DELIMITER ;
```

NB
The other use of ';' within your procedure definition is correct, because you want everything within the create statement to to be processed together.

Comment: I changed that line (and that line only) and it gave me this: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1". Taking the | out of the first line also gives me an error. It is even giving me lengthy errors when I try to copy and execute example code my professor gave in our notes

Comment: I've updated my answer for the additional error on the LAST line.

Comment: Man, really all I had to do was switch the top 2 lines (or do it your way, with a 3rd |) and put a freaking space. A space I had no clue I needed, at the end between DELIMITER and the ; .....man, that's aggravating. How was I supposed to figure that out?! Anyways, thanks for help!

Comment: mysql's own IDE (mysql workbench) would have highlighted that there were errors on both of those lines which would have given you somewhere to start looking but not tell you exactly what the problem was. Error messages in mysql are very good at highlighting the location of the error which is always at the start of the text it quotes or, as here, just before. Be wary when the message says "at line 1", that indicates the first line of that particular statement, so DELIMITER was  on line 1 of its statement despite being on your line 7 and not the use of DELIMITER on your actual line 1.